# Force execution order in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, execution

I have a set of conditions in my where clause like

```
WHERE id > 123456 
AND type LIKE 'type%'
```

The issue is that I would like the query to run the integer comparison first, as it signficantly decreases the amount of data that the string comparison needs to run.

However, the optimizer chooses to run the string comparison first forcing it to run extremely slowly.

Is there a way to force the execution order of my where clause?

Comment: How are you even determining it "chooses to run the string comparison first"?

Comment: @shawnt00 In my data base, a string comparison on millions of rows takes a significantly longer time to run vs an integer comparison. 

If the built in optimizer were working correctly, applying the integer comparison would cut down the run time. I tested both of these individually.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: When I run the string comparison on a subset of the database which has already by partitioned on my id integer comparison (splitting the query in my example into two separate queries), it runs in a significantly shorter time. Theoretically, I don't know for certain that it is choosing to run the string comparison first. But, if the optimizer is running the query with the same runtime as running the string comparison first in a separate query, I'll let you make the educated guess here.

Comment: Have you looked at query plans or indexes?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (MySQL, MS SQL, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about forcing it to run in a certain order but what if you used a cte?

Pretty hacky but maybe workable?

```
WITH cte_yourdata AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    yourTable
    WHERE   id > 123456 
)

SELECT  *
FROM    cte_yourdata
WHERE   type LIKE 'type%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I'm trying to see if there is a way to accomplish this within one query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is declarative language hence it, in general, does not allow you to specify order of execution of conditions. You have several possibilities though:

- define index on `id` and not on `type`
- define index on both `id` and `type` and ensure `id` column is more selective (narrowing result) than `type` column. You haven't described your data.
- in Oracle, use `/*+ INDEX(...)*/` hint to enforce proper index
- use materialized CTE

Please specify your db vendor and explain plan of your query for more precise answer.